# How to use the value in external js file in script tag of html?

Tags: javascript, html

Because the value is private data, it must be declared externally.
The basic API usage is as follows.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=APPKEY"></script>
```

I made the code as follows.(I know this is weird. but i can't find solution.)

```
<script src = "../src/const/mapkey.js"></script>
<script id = "mapKeyScript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
      const APPKEY = mapkey;
      document.getElementById("mapKeyScript").src = '//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=' + APPKEY;
</script>
```

But, It doesn't work.
What I'm seeing is an error caused by not declaring a variable map.
This can also happen when api authentication isn't working properly.
How to i solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe like this will work better for you:
`<script src="../src/const/mapkey.js"></script>`
Make sure the mapkey.js file contains the following line:

```
const mapkey = "YOUR_MAP_API_KEY";
```

Next, add an empty script tag with an id attribute:

```
<script id="mapKeyScript"></script>
```

enter the final script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  const APPKEY = mapkey;
  document.getElementById("mapKeyScript").src =
    "//dapi.kakao.com/v2/maps/sdk.js?appkey=" + APPKEY;
</script>
```

I hope this helps you